# admob add says it needs more space

Tags: android, admob

I have an add page set up with a button to close out of the add. Everything works fine and builds fine but when it loads up the logcat says it needs more space. I am not sure exactly what to do. here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/ad"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >

</com.google.ads.AdView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/close"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
android:text="Close" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat

```
    09-23 20:11:40.773: E/Trace(1829): error opening trace file: No such file or directory   
    (2)
    09-23 20:11:40.833: D/dalvikvm(1829): GC_CONCURRENT freed 166K, 3% free 10960K/11207K,  
    paused 17ms+0ms, total 20ms
    09-23 20:11:40.843: E/ActivityThread(1829): Failed to find provider info for 
    com.google.plus.platform
    09-23 20:11:40.853: I/Ads(1829): To get test ads on this device, call 
    adRequest.addTestDevice("980DE23A7222CD534B74241E4489EE78");
    09-23 20:11:40.883: D/dalvikvm(1829): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads497157569.jar'   
    (bootstrap=0) ---
    09-23 20:11:40.893: D/dalvikvm(1829): DexOpt: --- END 'ads497157569.jar' (success) ---
    09-23 20:11:40.893: D/dalvikvm(1829): DEX prep   
    '/data/data/com.androidsleepmachine.gamble/cache/ads497157569.jar': unzip in 0ms,  
    rewrite 14ms
    09-23 20:11:40.903: I/Ads(1829): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script 
    src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script> 
 <script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"643367869323117782   8","seq_num":"1","slotname":"a1523f906423032","u_w":384,"msid":"com.androidsleepmachine.gamble","cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.androidsleepmachine.gamble","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":1,"kw":[],"u_sd":2,"ms":"ZylCUJ2S3Vg0QN_Z3XlYac5EGnYGGYL9Y32scQh75uP_FmS5Fnsl7xl-tY3raOaanZTAtxFw_XEZ5rTeonWEsOoP87irEF6B6vMK4-cTWPyhpav4QawADXCfUzvVHw5Cvy4RPWPxnVakM_ZHhxJIaDZWKPA_Krm39mzjXuNZXPldGFHxoJnGDQqmxqvjAABo0ACRMs2n87KyXdNH9ncwaUn4bUpWsokuEGCdL4HfN6pWCMxosHCfLmhqtcRuFLyXbUkvilt4Veg7eHJ-mP1J-uXFLjA2bFZD0NBnZV6wSNkhvW_4fyCYOckqwcEJRvMLGfY1rsrM_qYU7IRGyUXF3Q","isu":"980DE23A7222CD534B74241E4489EE78","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":592,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
09-23 20:11:40.916: D/libEGL(1829): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
09-23 20:11:40.916: D/(1829): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb89fc3a8, tid 1829
09-23 20:11:40.935: D/libEGL(1829): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
09-23 20:11:40.935: D/libEGL(1829): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
09-23 20:11:40.973: W/EGL_emulation(1829): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-23 20:11:40.973: D/OpenGLRenderer(1829): Enabling debug mode 0
09-23 20:11:41.023: D/dalvikvm(1829): GC_CONCURRENT freed 260K, 4% free 11125K/11527K, paused 15ms+0ms, total 17ms
09-23 20:11:41.023: W/EGL_emulation(1829): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-23 20:11:41.178: D/webviewglue(1829): nativeDestroy view: 0xb89df7e8
09-23 20:11:41.293: I/Ads(1829): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=6433678693231177828&seq_num=1&u_w=384&msid=com.androidsleepmachine.gamble&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.androidsleepmachine.gamble&hl=en&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=1&kw&u_sd=2&ms=ZylCUJ2S3Vg0QN_Z3XlYac5EGnYGGYL9Y32scQh75uP_FmS5Fnsl7xl-tY3raOaanZTAtxFw_XEZ5rTeonWEsOoP87irEF6B6vMK4-cTWPyhpav4QawADXCfUzvVHw5Cvy4RPWPxnVakM_ZHhxJIaDZWKPA_Krm39mzjXuNZXPldGFHxoJnGDQqmxqvjAABo0ACRMs2n87KyXdNH9ncwaUn4bUpWsokuEGCdL4HfN6pWCMxosHCfLmhqtcRuFLyXbUkvilt4Veg7eHJ-mP1J-uXFLjA2bFZD0NBnZV6wSNkhvW_4fyCYOckqwcEJRvMLGfY1rsrM_qYU7IRGyUXF3Q&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=592&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_so=p&imbf=%40installed_markets%40&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-240&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a1523f906423032&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eisu=U0_S98n8m0dIXN6tevM3ZRfIRtQDQFLNOo0Ouv3KG6JmxrOM0aTKZfjt_EU5kvhngw6mqGu_b8tIoHPxSbf7n2TpQ3Oqzd2GNWm3XIQDtVdjq3Olc-aHju78Iuyi__6h&et=2&jsv=55" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
09-23 20:11:41.293: I/Ads(1829): Ad url modified to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=6433678693231177828&seq_num=1&u_w=384&msid=com.androidsleepmachine.gamble&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.androidsleepmachine.gamble&hl=en&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=1&kw&u_sd=2&ms=ZylCUJ2S3Vg0QN_Z3XlYac5EGnYGGYL9Y32scQh75uP_FmS5Fnsl7xl-tY3raOaanZTAtxFw_XEZ5rTeonWEsOoP87irEF6B6vMK4-cTWPyhpav4QawADXCfUzvVHw5Cvy4RPWPxnVakM_ZHhxJIaDZWKPA_Krm39mzjXuNZXPldGFHxoJnGDQqmxqvjAABo0ACRMs2n87KyXdNH9ncwaUn4bUpWsokuEGCdL4HfN6pWCMxosHCfLmhqtcRuFLyXbUkvilt4Veg7eHJ-mP1J-uXFLjA2bFZD0NBnZV6wSNkhvW_4fyCYOckqwcEJRvMLGfY1rsrM_qYU7IRGyUXF3Q&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=592&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_so=p&imbf=8008&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-240&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a1523f906423032&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mrai    d1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eisu=U0_S98n8m0dIXN6tevM3ZRfIRtQDQFLNOo0Ouv3K
    G6JmxrOM0aTKZfjt_EU5kvhngw6mqGu_b8tIoHPxSbf7n2TpQ3Oqzd2GNWm3XIQDtVdjq3Olc-
    aHju78Iuyi__6h&et=2&jsv=55
    09-23 20:11:41.293: I/Ads(1829): Request scenario: Online server request.
    09-23 20:11:43.103: D/webviewglue(1829): nativeDestroy view: 0xb89df870
    09-23 20:11:43.103: I/Ads(1829): onReceiveAd()
    09-23 20:11:43.123: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has: 
    <590, 1134>
    09-23 20:11:43.123: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has: 
    <590, 1038>
    09-23 20:11:43.123: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has: 
    <590, 1028>
    09-23 20:11:43.123: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has:   
    <590, 932>
    09-23 20:11:43.123: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has:  
    <590, 1028>
    09-23 20:11:43.123: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has: 
    <590,   
    932>
    09-23 20:11:43.164: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has:   
    <590,    
    1084>
    09-23 20:11:43.164: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has: 
    <590,   988>
    09-23 20:11:43.164: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has: 
    <590, 
    978>
    09-23 20:11:43.164: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has: <590, 882>
09-23 20:11:43.176: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has: <590,     978>
    09-23 20:11:43.176: E/Ads(1829): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <640, 100>, Has: <590, 882>
```

Answer (score 1):

you set up the width to 320dp

```
android:layout_width="320dp"
```

try

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

try replacing your code with this

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I changed it to match_parent and it still does not work. it says the same error, Wants <640, 100> Has <590, 988>

Comment: did you put this in your manifest? <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        </activity>

Comment: i dont know if this is helpful but when the activity starts it looks like it is cropped, it looks like a screen inside a screen. hard to explain really but it does not look normal size at all. I dont know where I would be having that issue though because I am not changing the size anywhere

Comment: on my phone your code works fine... it look like this because of all the android:layout_align you did top,bottom it made the ad bigger not the ad it self but the size it takes in the parent

Comment: I have my code replaced with yours and when I open up the app on my phone and the emulator it only loads a small box for the layout

Comment: did you register at admob.com and got yours adUnitId?